# Notification and Database from two different Firebase Application in a single App

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

So here is my situation, I'm connected to **ApplicationA** project on firebase console to handle the notification. But I want to listen to a database from **ApplicationB** project also.

The thing is that I can only have one `google-services.json`, I have to choose between one or the other but not both. So, my question is, how can I specify to listen to a database from another app that the one from the `google-services.json`.

Since the update, the project link is handled internally by the json. Before the update, I was able to paste the entire link of the database I wanted to be listening to.

**Here is the way I'm listening to certain database path currently:**

```
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    fireActionUpdate = database.getReference("org/" + nameId + "/action");
    fireRuleResponse = database.getReference("org/" + nameId + "/notify");
```

**Before it was:**

```
    fireActionUpdate = new Firebase("https://yellow.firebaseio.com/org/" + nameId + "/action");
    fireRuleResponse = new Firebase("https://yellow.firebaseio.com/org/" + nameId + "/notify");
```

Comment: You can still perform the same, I recently did use one DB for both app for messaging and GCM implementation

Comment: @silverFox - Seems like an answer. Jaythaking - Have you tried it yet?

Comment: @silverFox's answer has the gist of it. Have a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634767/how-to-connect-to-more-than-one-firebase-database-from-an-android-app/37643374#37643374

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Your answer doesn't work -_-, first comment is that is crashed, I just don't understand why is got accepted

Comment: I ran with that code before I posted it. It works. If you have a crash about `[DEFAULT]` already existing, it is either because you didn't specify a name for the second app or because you also have a different problem.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm not even creating two app, if you read my question carefully, it also isn't a duplicate. I want to use both Notification and database from two different app. Not two database from 2 different app... It might be the same answer for both question but it's starting from two different issue

Comment: Re-opened. The problem is that you have two processes calling `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()` and they're getting into each other's way. [Searching for the error message](https://www.google.com/webhp#q=FirebaseApp+name+%5BDEFAULT%5D+already+exists) leads to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337080/initialize-firebase-references-in-two-separate-files-in-the-new-api

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen That's really weird though because it's there in my code only ONCE in the ``onCreate`` of a service... There only one process for each service in Android so I'm lost here...

Comment: The only workaround I've found so far is to check if it already exist in a try catch... which is kind of ugly

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen If you are willing, we could check this in the chat and come back with an answer later?

Comment: The problem is always the same: there are two processes (or two places in a single process) initializing the FirebaseApp and they lead to conflicts. The cause is sometimes in your own code, but more often then not there is a library used that introduces a second process. Common examples of such libraries are crash reporting tools such as (yes ironically) Firebase's own Crash Reporting (we're working on a fix for that one btw).

Comment: There you go, that last sentence should be the accepted answer to my question... I was getting the error by that Crash Reporting tool and I though I was doing something wrong. I'll edit my question as it wasn't really clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is if you want to bind two application to the same `Firebase Database`, yet wants to use all the features like `FCM`.

Please follow these steps

1. Download `google-services.json` for the both the projects from the firebase console.
2. Let's say **Application A** is connected to **Main Database** and the json file is **file1**, similarly for **Application B**, the DB is **Sub Database** and **File 2**.
3. Go to the **File1** and copy the header except `project_number`& `project_id.
   Basically keep the`Firebase_url`&&`storage_bucket` same for both the apps.
4. Also keep the `client id` and `api key` same for both the projects.

Now you are all set.

To connect to a `Firebase database` like before follow the below code

```
        DatabaseReference baseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://<APP_NAME>.firebaseio.com/");
```

Perform the rest of the operations as usual.

Hopefully they don't push another update to break this rules :D

NOTE: These changes are tested, I'm using it for my 2 separate apps for messaging purpose with FCM integrated

For few known issues which I ended up with, you may check this code I have posted as well [Android not receiving Firebase Push Notification - MismatchSenderId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444560/android-not-receiving-firebase-push-notification-mismatchsenderid)

Happy Coding!!