# Web Push giving invalid senderid error in curl command

Tags: firebase

Curl command gives following error mentioned below

```
{"multicast_id":8323537220712392134,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"MismatchSenderId"}]}
```

Comment: I have had the same question, please make sure the sender id is matching
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444560/android-not-receiving-firebase-push-notification-mismatchsenderid?s=1|4.0755

Comment: I already matched the sender id and  it is correct ..... also i have generated multiple senderid produces same result